# How to disable DatePicker interaction(for selecting date) for one textfield in swift"

Tags: swift, datepicker, textfield

I am using `datePicker` for **fromDateTf** and **toDateTf**  textfields.. now i need to make toDateTf's date picker interaction disable(means date shouldn't select) if fromDateTf textfield text is empty.. how?

for datepicker

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 216))


class PostServiceRequestVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var toDateTf: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fromDateTf: UITextField!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fromDateTf.addInputViewDatePicker(target: self, selector: #selector(doneButtonPressed), tag: 0)
    toDateTf.addInputViewDatePicker(target: self, selector: #selector(doneButtonPressed), tag: 1)
            
    
}


@objc func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let arr = [fromDateTf,toDateTf]
    
    let current = arr[sender.tag]
    if let datePicker = current?.inputView as? UIDatePicker {
        current?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        
        current?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
            
}



extension UITextField {

func addInputViewDatePicker(target: Any, selector: Selector, tag: Int) {
    

    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    self.inputView = datePicker
    
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        datePicker.sizeToFit()
    }
    let todaysDate = Date()

    datePicker.minimumDate = todaysDate
    
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 44))
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPressed))
    let doneBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
    toolBar.setItems([cancelBarButton, flexibleSpace, doneBarButton], animated: false)

    doneBarButton.tag = tag
    
    self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

@objc func cancelPressed() {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
}
}
```

with the above code i am able to select dates for two textfields.. but

**here fromDateTf.text is empty so want to disable interaction for toDateTf's datepicker**

[image]

**i want user should select fromdate first.. without fromdate i do not want to give access  to select todate** how?... please help me

**EDIT:** according to below answer if i add that code in `viewDidLoad` then all the time `toDateTf` stopping me to show datepicker and select date

so i have added that code in  `doneButtonPressed` so here for the first time i am bale to show datepicker and select date.. but from the 2nd time if the `fromDateTf` is empty then working.. but its not working for the 1st time.. for first time also if fromDateTf is empty then `toDateTf.isEnabled = false` should work.. how to achieve please do help.

```
   @objc func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let arr = [fromDateTf,toDateTf]

    let current = arr[sender.tag]
    if let datePicker = current?.inputView as? UIDatePicker {

        if fromDateTf.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

               toDateTf.isEnabled = false
            
            } else {
               toDateTf.isEnabled = true
        }
        current?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

        current?.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function that checks whether or not the fromDateTf is empty, and adjust the UI accordingly:

```
func checkForText() {

     if fromDateTF.text == "" { //you can also use .isEmpty if you'd rather

        toDateTf.isEnabled = false 

     } else {

        toDateTf.isEnabled = true

     }
```

Then, you can call this function in your ViewDidLoad and any subsequent time you change anything with your textboxes. It'll be a good idea to add in the else part of it so that when you fill in your fromDateTf, it reEnables the other one.